# ARCore : should I add "uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000""?

Tags: java, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, arcore

In the ARCore demo app Preview 2, I don't see the following line in the manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```

Whereas it is required in the openGL tutorial here :

https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html

So, should I include it or not ?

By the way, is is written in the openGL tutorial :

```
If your application uses texture compression, you must also declare which compression formats your app supports, so that it is only installed on compatible devices.

<supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture" />
<supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture" />
```

I don't know what "If your application uses texture compression" means (beginner in openGL). How do I know if my app uses compression? Should I include these 2 lines in my manifest ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use OpenGL ES in your app [you should specify so](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)  in the manifest, same goes for texture compression, if you're compressing your textures and uploading them using `glCompressedTexImage2D` you're using texture compression...